React native - Different screen values between JS and native side
I'm trying to get device's screen size on native side (kotlin) but I noticed that JS gives me different values:
kotlin:
private val density = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density.toInt()
private val windowWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels / density -> 800
private val windowHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels / density -> 1276

react-native:
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get( 'window' ).width -> 600.938
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get( 'window' ).height -> 958.497

Why is this happening and how can I get the same value than react-native on the native side?

Most likely RN is measuring it in CSS "pixels".  A CSS pixel has nothing to do with an actual pixel, a CSS pixel is 1/96th of an inch.  It's the same concept as Android's dp (1/160th of an inch) except they decided to reuse the name and confuse everyone.

Also, why are you dividing by density on native?  DO you want the actual number of pixels?  Then no need to divide.  Density is used to convert pixels to dp.

@GabeSechan I'm just trying to get on native side the same value than I have on JS side without passing these values as a prop. Without dividing by density the value I get is even higher than those values I'm getting now
